# Creating new format in SAS

Tags: format, sas

I would like to create a format in SAS, that converts float into text, e.g.
1.7 should be converted into 'one point seven'. Float contains three symbols only - a digit, a point and a digit.

I know this could be solved by creating data set containing all variations and then format based on this set, but it doesn't satisfy me at all.

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/68954/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p10b4qouzgi6sqn154ipglazix2q.htm

Comment: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201455.htm

Comment: Please post what you've tried. You can refer to the above links on creating a function using a proc fcmp and the word format. Or you could do a one liner in a data step